# How to change a row color of datagridview without looping in datatable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

Datagridview1 was bounding with Datatable. This DataTable is stored color value for painting each row. And a BindingSource was used for filtering.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable    
Dim dcColor As New DataColumn("Color", GetType(Color))
Dim dcChecked As New DataColumn("Checked", GetType(Boolean))
Dim bs As New BindingSource

dt.Columns.Add(dcColor)
dt.Columns.Add(dcChecked )
bs.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```

I need to get color value from each datarow in Datatable then use it for paint each row in datagridview.

And if I have a lot of datarow (1000-10,0000 rows) and I need to filtered Datagridview like this

```
bs.Filter = "Checked = True"
```

That it's mean I must iterate in all datarows for get each color value and set back to datagridviewrow.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Paint
    Try
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim needColor As Color = dr.Item("Color")
            DataGridView1.Rows(???).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = needColor
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        m_logger.AppendLog(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It isn't bad for large datatable.

How to Datagridviewrow by using a value from datarow?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to show 1000+ rows in just one page! I`d go with paging.

Comment: Use [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2) event.

Comment: use the RowPrePaint event or CellFormatting abd paint just the row the event is being called for

Comment: A DataGridView `Paint` event that contains a `foreach` loop is something you really have to avoid. Add the Color field to a hidden column and color the Row using, for example, the [RowPrePaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint) event.